# Hiding Some nuget packages in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity server that also acts as the NuGet server. The server has a number of packages that I want to expose to authenticated users, using the `Authenticated Feed URL`, but it also has some packages that I do not want to be available.

Because we use Octopus Deploy, our projects are packed using octopack, so they also appear NuGet server.

Can I set TeamCity to restrict which NuGet packages authenticated users can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent OctoPack from publishing the output nupkg packages by setting the `OctoPackPublishPackagesToTeamCity` system parameter to false (it [defaults to true](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack/blob/master/source/tools/OctoPack.targets#L34)):

```
system.OctoPackPublishPackagesToTeamCity = false
```

This should solve your problem. As far as I know, the only way to restrict what appears on the TeamCity authenticated nuget feed is to simply not publish a package as an artifact.

Comment: Wont that stop Octopus Deploy from seeing it for the deployment?

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for this: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1229

Comment: Yes, it will prevent OD from seeing the packages as they won't be published to the TeamCity feed.  It's a good reason to either switch to using the built-in OD feed (which actually reduces proliferation of packages as OD caches the packages anyway if they're sourced from the TeamCity feed), or to use a separate hosted feed for deployment purposes.  I've flip-flopped between hosting options a few times, and have settled for using OD as my deployment package host...  this may or may not be an option for you, but ultimately the feed is being used for multiple purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to review our setup. Thanks Steve.

Comment: No problem; FYI there is built-in support in OctoPack for automatically publishing the packages to an Octopus feed as well, using OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp -  https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack/blob/master/source/tools/OctoPack.targets#L27